# WPF datagrid date column with system custom short date format

Tags: wpf, datetime, wpfdatagrid

This is slightly different wrinkle to the custom date format threads with WPF datagrids.

My Win7 box has a custom short date string defined in the Control Panel as dd-MM-yy.  I want a date column in a DataGrid to use that setting for display.  The view model has a DateTime called 'Date'.

I tried this:

```
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataCondition" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=d}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Comment}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

The date column shows up as m/d/yyyy.  Doesn't the DataGrid use the system short date setting, irregardless if it's custom or not?

WPF DatePickers seem to work differently.  The custom short date format is used even without a StringFormat (and being bound directly to a DateTime in the view model).

I can get around this problem in the DataGrid by creating a string property in the view model (Date -> DateFormatted) where the getter uses DateTime.ToShortDateString, but I'm not sure this is the best way to do this.  And I haven't worked out the binding TwoWay part yet... :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a converter and use it in the binding at the datetime column. A class that inherits IValueConverter. Receives a DateTime and returns a String.

Comment: I completely fail to understand how is this the answer! and this same solution was given with complete code by klut and yet thats not the answer even.

Comment: Im sorry but I agree with @Maverik.

Comment: Feel free to change the answer. I posted only the logic how to solve it with a converters. Converters are easy to read and learn about. So I saved time by leaving out code. I may have been accepted because I answered before the other answer. No problem for me if it's changed. But my answer is not incorrect, so I don't think I deserve the down-votes.

Comment: Well i may have disagreed with this being selected as the answer (i never said its the wrong answer, but there's a better answer) but i wasn't the one who down voted you. I'd guess there are others who agree with me.

Comment: The question owner i free to change the accepted solution. No problem for me.

Answer (score 12):

Try setting/binding this as your `Converter`:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DateTime), typeof(String))]
public class DateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private const string _format = "dd-MM-yy";

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;

        return date.ToString(_format);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact((string) value, _format, culture);
    }

}
```

Then set up your XAML like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfDataGridMisc:DateConverter x:Key="dateConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks!  But, the short date format I used in the OP was an example only.  The ConvertBack I need to write needs to be generic.  Maybe a DateTime.TryParse.

Comment: Note that you may need to add support for null values (depending on your case).

Answer (score 9):

I think the solution is rather simple. The `StringFormat` you're using is invalid so it gets ignored and `DataGridTextColumn` resorts to default format. If you instead specify `dd` as `StringFormat`, it works as you expect.

so your final binding will look like this (including TwoWay):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=dd, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

However, please note that this is going to be confusing in edit mode as even though column is showing you just a number (the day) it will actually expect you to write in a valid date before it accepts that input and formats it again as you request it to. You can work around this by using a `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead and specifying `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate` in there.

Comment: The shortest, clearest and easiest to implement solution out there! Thank You! :)

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to configure the date time format.

VB Code

```
Imports System.Windows.Data

Public Class DateTimeToString
    Implements IValueConverter

    Private _Format As String
    Public Property Format() As String
        Get
            Return _Format
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, _
                            ByVal targetType As System.Type, _
                            ByVal parameter As Object, _
                            ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object _
                            Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim DateTimeValue As DateTime
        If DateTime.TryParse(value, DateTimeValue) Then
            Return DateTimeValue.ToString(_Format)
        End If
        Return value
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, _
                                ByVal targetType As System.Type, _
                                ByVal parameter As Object, _
                                ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object _
                                Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Dim StringValue As String = value.ToString
        Dim DateTimeValue As DateTime
        If DateTime.TryParse(StringValue, DateTimeValue) Then
            Return DateTimeValue
        End If
        Return value
    End Function
End Class
```

C# Code

```
public class DateTimeToString : IValueConverter
{
    public string Format { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime DateTimeValue = (DateTime)value;
        return DateTimeValue.ToString(Format);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string strValue = value.ToString();
        DateTime DateTimeValue;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(strValue, out DateTimeValue))
            return DateTimeValue;
        return value;
    }
}
```

XAML Code

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding BirthDate, Converter={StaticResource DateToString}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `UICulture` when your application starts to what it should be. Then it will use the right formatting from the computer. The XAML resources always default to `en-US` you see.