# Datetime format programmatically WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in a window of WPF, it can have different columns (which are chosen programmatically). Often many of them are Dates, but they are by default formatted as mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt.
I however need all those fields shown as dd/mm/yyyy. I could find how to do it in xaml defined columns, but all my columns are programmatical, so I need to do it either in c# or define in XAML all datetime columns to be formatted this way.

Answer (score 1):

Found the ability to make all DateTime columns formatted by handling the AutoGeneratingColumn of the DataGrid and adding binding whenever the type is DateTime

```
if (e.PropertyType == Type.GetType("System.DateTime")) {
    DataGridTextColumn col = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
    col.Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) { StringFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" };
}
```

Found the solution here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f32a6639-60c8-47c7-9ae0-dceb221fd9cf/string-format-for-the-datagrid-column?forum=wpf

Comment: This did not work for me when AutogenerateColumns was false. The event simply didn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

Write a converter, as explained in one of the answers to [WPF datagrid date column with system custom short date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283068/wpf-datagrid-date-column-with-system-custom-short-date-format).

By passing execution to code rather than xaml you have full control over the string that is outputted. I use mine to show mixture of long date and short time (which confused the heck out of the xaml parser).